# Django set relation between two models fields

Tags: django, django-models

I need to create relation between two model fields (without using any of ForeignKey methods), for example:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True) 

class StatClient(models.Model):
    client_login = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

The relation need to by 1 to 1. I mean login need to by equal to client_login in another model and vice versa.

To make this work i can overwrite for each model save() method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from * import StatClient
    data = StatClient(client_login=login)
    data.save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Problem is when the data is changed based on php code direct in mysql. Then Django is not aware of any changes have been made! In this case one option is to monitor all data every 1 second but this can't be done because of performance.

Is there any solution to do this without touching php code?

Comment: Why can't you use foreign keys? They're _meant_ for this sort of thing.

Comment: @AKX because one model is created for collecting changes made by php code and another for rest of Django.